# Is it possible to define conditions on relations in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid

Is it possible to define relations with conditions as in active record, like...

```
    class Supplier 
      include Mongoid::Document
      has_one :account, -> { where(confirmed:true) }
    end
```

I know, I could use scopes instead, but that's just a stupid example adopted from active record documentation. http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html don't mention anything in this direction.

Comment: I think that it is not supported in mongoid: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1921